# Creating a responsive and uniform grid layout in pure CSS for variable number of images, all tiles fitting the size of the largest element

Tags: css

[edit : **preamble**]

**Regardless of the nature of your answer, please enhance your arguments with technical references from reliable sources. Thanks in advance**.

[Question]

I'm trying to create a pure CSS responsive grid layout for images with variable number of elements, all in their original resolution, all centered in their cell. The largest image must be the reference, its cell must exactly fit it, and the grid has to be responsive to the space available (ie create rows only if necessary).

So far so good, the grid is almost ok for me, but with my approach, we must know the exact size of the largest square image if we want it to be the reference (with no space around).

Maybe it's not possible to achieve this with pure CSS. I'm not able to, I hope you can give me some tips.

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto, 100px));
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  object-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
</div>
```

It should be great if I was not dependent of a hard-coded value (100px).

Comment: Unfortunately, the specification for [Syntax of `repeat()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#repeat-syntax) includes "Automatic repetitions (`auto-fill` or `auto-fit`) cannot be combined with fully intrinsic or flexible sizes" and has to be a <fixed-size>. Therefore, this would have to be done using a (server-side or client-side) script to determine the largest width and then write the CSS.

Comment: Hi @TimR and many thanks for your research efforts, the citation, and the link. As it is a good candidate for the accepted answer, I suggest you to post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to solve your problem with only css. As already mentioned, `auto-fill` requires a fixed size.
Therefore, I suggest using a minimum of javascript code and setting up a css variable.
In the example below also is taken into account prevented from "jumping" after calculating the width of the image:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  /* Looking for the widest image. */
  const largestImgWidth = [...document.querySelectorAll('.gallery img')].reduce( (prev, current) => prev = current.offsetWidth > prev ? current.offsetWidth : prev, 0);
  /* Set largestImgWidth in the css variable */
  document.querySelector('.gallery').style.setProperty('--largest-img-width', largestImgWidth + 'px')
}
```

```css
.gallery {
  /* Initial col width */
  --largest-img-width: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fill, minmax( var(--largest-img-width), 1fr) );
  /* Hide until the grid is formed */
  opacity: 0;
}

.gallery[style] {
  /* Show it after forming the grid */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. I really appreciate and applause the technical elegance of your code,  it sounds like you are a code crafter :) Since your answer is a candidate for the bounty, maybe it would be valuable for future readers to point out the technical limitations with references. Thanks in advance, have a nice day.

Comment: @Philippe Thanks for the comment! I have added some explanation to my code.

Comment: Thanks again and congratulations for the conciseness and for the efficiency of your code. Unsung hero, here is your bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

snippet little better only but still 100px

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
</div>
```

Masonry layout still not implemented in grid, it's coming but not yet.
After you could use masonry plug-in, check here:
https://masonry.desandro.com/

Or with javascript, getboudingclient rect you check all img size

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. You're wright, in fact this is masonry. So, you think that there is no way to let CSS compute the largest size automatically yet? (thanks for the link btw)

Comment: At the moment, css only, no I don't think so...

Comment: So, according to your answers, I would have to use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--column-width), 1fr));` , and set this variable with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep all the images same size as grid.

```css
.gallery {
            display: grid;
              grid-gap: 1rem;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto, 100px));
            justify-items: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
            
        .gallery img {
            width: 100%; /* changed to 100% from auto */
            height: 100%; /* changed to 100% from auto */
            object-fit: fill; /* changed to fill from scale-down */
            object-position: center center;
        }
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. With your code, the images don't keep their original resolution / size. The point is that the size off all the cells / tiles must fit the size of the largest image, which is the reference. The other images must stay smaller and centered. My preoccupation is that I must hard code 100px, as it the size of the largest image. I'd like it to be automatically computed.

Comment: Use `max-width: 100%` instead of using `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`, if both dimensions are set that will - obviously - override the inherent aspect-ratio of the `<img>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your last comment setting css variable with javascript, you can directly put the value in the style.

```js
const searchMaxWidth = () => {
  let mw = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('.gallery img').forEach(el => {
    if (el.getBoundingClientRect().width > mw) mw = el.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  })
  console.log(mw);
  document.querySelector('.gallery').style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(auto-fill, minmax(' + mw + 'px, 1fr))';
}
window.addEventListener('load', searchMaxWidth);
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/25">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/75">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this new anwser. Yes indeed, using a css variable is not mandatory, just one of my habits : when reviewing the css you can directly see where it is modified by scripting. Your solution works, I voted for it. Nevertheless,  I going to start a bounty for a pure CSS solution, if any exists. If the bounty is not attributed, I will mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi. Thanks again for your answer and for all your efforts. Facing two equally valid technical answers, it was very hard for me to make a choice. The criteria of code conciseness and efficiency of the other answer increased its value for me.

Comment: @philippe, by the way I tried several other solutions with grid (implicit, explicit, auto, fr, min-content, max-content...), even I tried with flex. In all solutions, the problem is browser needs at least somewhere 1 "real" size, only 1, but 1, to calculate all other values. That's for CSS only solution: you rely entirely in browser calculation. Otherwise you have to go javascript way where you can make little to all calculation you want.