# Align items neatly in grid

Tags: css

I have some div `.test` with `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;` because I want the column width to be like flex effect which depends on the element width, and also `justify-content: start;` to align the column to the left and this is also why I use `auto` and not `1fr` because I don't want the columns being stretched to the longer width possible.

The problem is that I don't know how to align the column neatly like a table does, s you can see from the example below, the p `.target` from the second div `.test` is longer than the first one, what I try to achieve is to make all other column width follow the longest one.

P.S.: I don't want to use table. I also can use JavaScript to find the longest one and set all others' width to this. I just want to see if there is an easy solution with CSS only.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.test {
    column-gap: 30px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    justify-content: start;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
}

.flex {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p class="target">Hello</p>
  <p><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <p class="target">Hellooo</p>
  <p><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

For example, it looks like this in a table:

```css
td:nth-child(2) {
    position: relative;
  width: 120px;
}

.flex {
  white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hellooo</td>
    <td><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note that the all the second columns start together even the first column "hellooo" is longer from the second row.

Comment: [This bountied question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76390621) seems to be exactly about what you're looking for. That is, if the number of columns is not known beforehand. Is it?

Comment: It sounds like [creating div like table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663566/21370707) Isn't it?

Comment: @InSync The number of column is not problem in my case, mt problem is cannot align the column neatly like a table does.

Comment: @cyz3a5c0v1 How would that look like, then? Please edit your question to include that too, as the more details the better, as long as they are not excessive.

Comment: @Newbee Similar but not exactly. I mentioned that the reason I use `auto` in `grid-template-columns` and `justify-content: start;` is because I don't want the column to be the longest possible like `width: 100%;`. The reference you have given is like `1fr` which stretch to the longest possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your HTML so as to add all items inside a single grid and use `inline-grid`:

```html
<div class="test">
  <p class="target">Hello</p>
  <p><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p class="target">Hellooo</p>
  <p><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

```css
.test {
  display: inline-grid;
}
```

Note that you will have to target the second element of each row with a more complex `nth-child`:

```css
p:nth-child(3n + 2) {}
```

Try it:

```css
.test {
  display: inline-grid;
}

p:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
}


/* Demo only */

p {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}

.test {
  column-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  justify-content: start;
}

.flex {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p class="target">Hello</p>
  <p><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p class="target">Hellooo</p>
  <p><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the grid columns to behave like a table you need to place your items in a single grid container, not 2 separate ones:

```
<div class="test">
    <p class="target">Hello</p>
    <p><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p class="target">Hellooo</p>
    <p><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></p>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

To set the width of the second element of each row, you can simply specify the width in your grid layout:

```
grid-template-columns: auto 120px auto;
```

But if we get rid of the `p:nth-child(2)` selector now, we'd have the `.flex` element positioned absolutely against the grid, and not the `p` element, which messes up the layout.

But you can actually get rid of the absolute positioning altogether without messing up your layout and apply your overflow properties to all the grid items like this:

```
.test > * {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

And here is the resulting, cleaner code:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.test {
  column-gap: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 120px auto;
  justify-content: start;
}

.test > * {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p class="target">Hello</p>
  <p><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p class="target">Hellooo</p>
  <p><span class="flex">Helloooooooooooooo</span></p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```